# Geo Coordinates offset - airport runways diagram

Tags: javascript, math, svg, coordinates, geo

I'm trying to generate an airport runways digram, something like this:

[image: airport runways]

Each airport has a list of runways represented as follows:

```js
const runways = [
    {
      identifier1: "110L",
      identifier2: "28R",
      length: 3107,
      width: 75,

      latitude1: 37.66247544,
      longitude1: -122.12726156,

      latitude2: 37.65822686,
      longitude2: -122.11795339,
    },
    {
      identifier1: "10R",
      identifier2: "28L",
      length: 5694,
      width: 150,
      
      latitude1: 37.66204453,
      longitude1: -122.12979078,

      latitude2: 37.65426,
      longitude2: -122.11273375,
    },
  ];
```

As you can see each runway has starting and ending geo points.
For visuals I'm using [svg-airports](https://github.com/Gregable/svg-airports), the above example of the runways is represented by this:

```html
<airport-diagram width="200" height="200">
  <airport-runway
    length-ft="3107"
    true-heading="119"
    offset-angle="29"
    offset-x="300"
    offset-y="1000"
  >
    <runway-id name="10L" pattern="left"></runway-id>
    <runway-id name="28R" pattern="right"></runway-id>
  </airport-runway>
  <airport-runway
    length-ft="5694"
    true-heading="119"
    offset-angle="29"
    offset-x="300"
    offset-y="-1000"
  >
    <runway-id name="10R" pattern="right"></runway-id>
    <runway-id name="28L" pattern="left"></runway-id>
  </airport-runway>
</airport-diagram>
```

As you can see that each runway has the following values

- length
- true-heading
- offset-angle
- offset-x
- offset-y

I'm able to provide the length as I already have that info from my `airport` and I'm calculating the true-heading (bearing) as follows:

```js
function radians(n) {
  return n * (Math.PI / 180);
}
function degrees(n) {
  return n * (180 / Math.PI);
}

function getBearing(startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong) {
  startLat = radians(startLat);
  startLong = radians(startLong);
  endLat = radians(endLat);
  endLong = radians(endLong);

  var dLong = endLong - startLong;

  var dPhi = Math.log(
    Math.tan(endLat / 2.0 + Math.PI / 4.0) /
      Math.tan(startLat / 2.0 + Math.PI / 4.0)
  );
  if (Math.abs(dLong) > Math.PI) {
    if (dLong > 0.0) dLong = -(2.0 * Math.PI - dLong);
    else dLong = 2.0 * Math.PI + dLong;
  }

  return (degrees(Math.atan2(dLong, dPhi)) + 180.0) % 180.0;
}
```

The question is, can I calculate the `offset-angle`, `offset-x`, and `offset-y` based on the geo coordinates between the runways ?

P.S: the offset values are in feet.

Comment: Convert longitude/latitude to Cartesian coordinates. Then it should be easy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert longitude/latitude to Cartesian coordinates. Then it should be easy.
I assume the conversion is the problem.

For an airport (relatively small), a simple [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) can be  used.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
   <script src="t.js"></script>
   <script src="svg-airports-1.0.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// t.js
// important parts within ////// commments
const runways = [
   {
      identifier1: "110L",
      identifier2: "28R",
      length: 3107,
      width: 75,
      latitude1: 37.66247544,
      longitude1: -122.12726156,
      latitude2: 37.65822686,
      longitude2: -122.11795339,
   }, {
      identifier1: "10R",
      identifier2: "28L",
      length: 5694,
      width: 150,
      latitude1: 37.66204453,
      longitude1: -122.12979078,
      latitude2: 37.65426,
      longitude2: -122.11273375,
   },
];

function runways2html(runways,scale=1.0) {
   //
   airport = document.createElement("airport-diagram")
   document.body.appendChild(airport)
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   const radians = n => n * (Math.PI / 180)
   const degrees = n => n * (180 / Math.PI)
   const avg = (v1,v2) => .5*(v1+v2)
   const lon2x = lon => R*(lon-lon0)*cosLat0
   const lat2y = lat => R*(lat-lat0)
   //
   var lons = runways.map(({longitude1,longitude2}) => [longitude1,longitude2]).flat().map(v => radians(v))
   var lats = runways.map(({latitude1,latitude2}) => [latitude1,latitude2]).flat().map(v => radians(v))
   var lonMax = Math.max(...lons)
   var lonMin = Math.min(...lons)
   var latMax = Math.max(...lats)
   var latMin = Math.min(...lats)
   var lon0 = avg(lonMin,lonMax)
   var lat0 = avg(latMin,latMax)
   var cosLat0 = Math.cos(lat0)
   var R = 20902000 // Earth radius in feet (??)
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   var [xMin,xMax] = [lonMin,lonMax].map(lon2x)
   var [yMin,yMax] = [latMin,latMax].map(lat2y)
   var width = xMax-xMin
   var height = yMax-yMin
   var [width,height] = [width,height].map(v => v*scale)
   airport.setAttribute("width",width)
   airport.setAttribute("height",height)
   //
   runways.forEach(runway => {
      var {
         identifier1,
         identifier2,
         length,
         width,
         latitude1,
         longitude1,
         latitude2,
         longitude2,
      } = runway
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      var [longitude1,longitude2,latitude1,latitude2] = [longitude1,longitude2,latitude1,latitude2].map(v => radians(v))
      var [x1,x2] = [longitude1,longitude2].map(lon2x)
      var [y1,y2] = [latitude1,latitude2].map(lat2y)
      var heading = Math.atan2(x2-x1,y2-y1)
      heading = degrees(heading)
      var x = avg(x1,x2)
      var y = avg(y1,y2)
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      var runway = document.createElement("airport-runway")
      runway.setAttribute("length-ft",length)
      runway.setAttribute("true-heading",heading)
      runway.setAttribute("offset-angle",0)
      runway.setAttribute("offset-x",x)
      runway.setAttribute("offset-y",y)
      var [id1,id2] = [0,1].map(i => document.createElement("runway-id"))
      id1.setAttribute("name",identifier1)
      id1.setAttribute("pattern",identifier1.endsWith("L")?"left":"right") // ??
      id2.setAttribute("name",identifier2)
      id2.setAttribute("pattern",identifier1.endsWith("L")?"right":"left") // ??
      runway.appendChild(id1)
      runway.appendChild(id2)
      airport.appendChild(runway)
   })
}

runways2html(runways,0.2)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have tried it out, it seems that the offsets are not accurate, this is what I'm getting https://i.imgur.com/VIbgvRN.png, the spaces between the runways are not as the original post screenshot, or am I missing something ? my current goal is to create X runways based on length and two geo points for each runway...

Comment: I am getting the same image. But it seems to be the result of the input geo points.. Also the points put on [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/'37.66247544,-122.12726156'/'37.65822686,-122.11795339'/'37.66204453,-122.12979078'/'37.65426,-122.11273375'/@37.6604699,-122.1292793,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m3!2m2!1d-122.1272616!2d37.6624754!1m3!2m2!1d-122.1179534!2d37.6582269!1m3!2m2!1d-122.1297908!2d37.6620445!1m3!2m2!1d-122.1127338!2d37.65426!3e0) seems to be more like the second result than your original image (where the runways are too far away from each other)..

Comment: Also note that length is redundant information, computable from the end points

Comment: I'll try a more complex airport with much more runways. Yes the length could be computable in that case... thank you again, I'll update you with the test...

Comment: amazingly it works with much more complex runways (apart from the fact that the width and height of the svg is somehow always assumed to be square, that's a TODO in the svg-airports.js I guess), I have made some changes to the original svg lines, apparently the width of the lines is too much for a space between runways, so I made it smaller in order to see the spaces clearly, which is just fine... any chance for a feedback about the size ratio of the svg ? being always square ? here's a pin for ORD airport https://codepen.io/hatemalimam/pen/MWjQmWK

Comment: I have hardcoded width and height. I made an edit, now it is a parameter (note the `airport.setAttribute("width",...)` and the line below)

Comment: Yeah, it was clear that it was hardcoded, but the problem isn’t in your example code, it’s in svg-airport script exactly [here](https://github.com/Gregable/svg-airports/blob/55078f730b26815d1b948d489bcdab375d7f8fef/svg-airports-1.0.js#L96). Basically I would never know the right height and width of each airport, I have around 20K airport in db :) so some are square and some are not... thank you again.

Comment: Aha, ok. You can convert `lonMax`, `lonMin`, `latMax`, `latMin` to `xy` and get bounding dimensions and set the SVG dimensions according to it

Comment: Would you give me the formula of the conversion  I really appreciate the help...

Comment: The formula is there, e.g. `xMin=lon2x(lonMin)`. I have modified the code to set the dimensions automatically. The full size is too large IMO, you can set the scale (here 0.2 is specified)

Comment: Hello, thank you... I have published a [React component](https://airport-discovery.github.io/airport-diagram/#/), thanks to your contribution, please let me know if I can mention you in the credits... you can contact me via mail (in my profile)...  Cheers.